# Windows sees my DVD player/writer, but it won't read/write any CDs or DVDs

Tags: windows-xp-embedded

My multi DVD writer (LG GSA-H12L) detects on Windows but does not read or write any CD or DVD

Comment: A *whole* CD or DVD? I think that's bad.

Comment: Is it showing status as writing in windows? Do you hear the disk spinning while writing?

Answer (score 1):

The device could be fine (This is why windows detects it), but the laser could be malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to blow out the drive with compressed air, it could just be dust on the laser tip, be careful not to blow water in and do so with care.